# Does Java follow Object Oriented Programming Model fully?

Tags: java, oop, object, jvm, private

The following code illustrates the situation:

```
class Human {

 private String heart = "default heart";

    public void control(Human h) {

            h.heart = "$%^&*@@!#^";
      }

   public String getHeart() {
    return heart;
    }
  }

 public class HumanTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Human deb = new Human();
    Human kate = new Human();

    System.out.println(deb.getHeart());
    kate.control(deb);
    System.out.println(deb.getHeart());

   }

 }
```

Here heart [private variable] of deb got modified unfortunately.  :)

Java allows the code to run without any error.But  is it justified to give a object the privilege to  access private member of other object even if the code is in the same class ? 
Shouldn't Java disallow this?

As I know, private means restricting access beyond the class source code. But the same concept is applied in the source code above. and the result is disastrous since a person's heart can't be modified by any random person .

Comment: Very few languages are pure OOP. All you need to read is `public static void main` to realise that main is run without an Object.

Comment: Your question isn't about OOP at all. It is about the access control mechanism in Java. It has no yes/no answer. Jim Gosling designed it that way: that's how it is. If you want to know why, it's either in the language specification, the JVM specification, or Jim's head.

Comment: so what you expect private member to be used by ?  if not used by public member then where do you think private member to be used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the result is disastrous, you shouldn't code the class so that it allows it. The "bug" is not caused by code external to the class, but by code of the class itself. So it's simply a bug in your code.

If Java did not allow it, you could only compare objects of the same class by their public attributes, for example, which would either break encapsulation (by exposing private stuff), and/or be very slow (by forcing to make defensive copies of the private attributes to make them available to other objects.

Answer (score 2):

Some languages have encapsulation at the object level, others (Java, C++) at the class level. It sounds like you're used to (or have just read about) encapsulation at the object level. Frankly, I find the class level much more natural, but perhaps that's just because C++ provided my introduction to programming with classes.  Class-level encapsulation makes some idioms (factory methods, copy constructors, comparison operators) much easier to write. With object-level encapsulation, you end up exposing more than you really want to just to be able to implement these features.

In any case, neither way is "correct" -- they're just different.

Answer (score 0):

Look into defensive copy to avoid this situation.  It is because java objects operate more like references.  The 'pointer' doesn't change, but once you know it you can change the value it contains.

http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=31551&seqNum=2

Answer (score 0):

This isn't breaking object orientation - it's about encapsulation of elements internal to a class.

It may seem silly that you can do this with this example but it's actually not a bad thing at all as far as I see it. The point of encapsulating elements of a class is so that other classes can't modify them - they can only see the public interface of class `Human` for instance to make changes. This means more than one person can work on the same project, writing different classes (or you can work on the same project at different times writing different classes) and they don't need to know the inner workings of the code.

However, the only place (bar reflection) you can access a private field directly in Human is *from* Human. When you're writing the Human class, if you choose to make modifications to private fields of other Human objects, that's up to you - but it's all contained within that one class, which is your design. If you do this in a way that's not appropriate, then it's a flaw in your design and not with Java - there's some cases where it makes perfect sense to do this!

Answer (score 0):

Well, the way I see it and this is just my interpretation of the private keyword, a private is private to the class and can be accessed inside the class. It is not restricted to instances of the class. Therefore you can't do kate.heart="xpto" in the "humantest" class because that would try to breach it's privacy, but using kate's code to alter deb's heart is allowed because it is being handled inside the class.

Answer (score 0):

Java language strictly following the Object oriented concept. Here also that's correct..ritght? Using the object of your class you are modifying your class's variables. But its upto the programmer who can have control over his objects.

Human's heart is private inside Human's class. But using the control method you are giving access to it from outside. That's why it gets modified..What's the problem in that.?